# Does "community" really need to bump so many low quality questions?

Tags: feature-request

Lately there are an awful lot of questions on this site with a notice like:

> **bumped to the homepage** by [Community ♦](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (time interval) ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

When in almost all cases they are really low grade questions that can not be answered because the OP never responded to some simple follow up questions.

Is this automated? Can the algorithm be fixed to discard questions where the OP never signed in again after the initial post?

Maybe simply limiting such bumps to like 1 per day would help.

Answer (score 7):

### VTC 'em away

This is what flagging to close/voting to close are for -- if the user drove-by and is long gone, and the question can't be answered, simply vote to close it as "unclear".

Comment: trust me when i get close vote privledges I will be using it

Comment: @agentp You can also downvote any question at no cost if you feel it's not valuable for the site, and in cases where the answers are not accepted or positively-scored, a system process nicknamed the Roomba may eventually close and/or delete them. [Voting down requires only 125 reputation](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 2):

## Flag them!

Even without voting to close, [flagging](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) is only 15 reputation.  Flagging the question is an easy way to get someone else to start the closing process and getting your input in.  That said, many of the Community questions are questions that can be answered now that Engineering is a bit older and has some better level expertise on questions that couldn't be answered, so only flag questions that are not salvageable, not questions that you personally couldn't answer.